# Want to connect my external mysql db to Shopify without using the apps

Tags: mysql, shopify, liquid

We have developed website using the shopify with timber.css. Now we have a requirement to connect external db to the website for some forms where customers can able to upload images. and that images should be saved in the external db. This should be done without using any apps. Which is the better way to achieve this?

Comment: Your requirements are unclear. What is the point of this? Shopify is a hosted platform, you won't be able to get it to hook into a MySQL database.

Comment: Shopify is a hosted platform. i agree that. i need the enquiry form where customers can write their names and description along with the images(upload option) in the form. so i wanna integrate my external db so that the form can be saved in my db. (or) is there any option where shopify can store that form in the shopify maintained db?

Comment: Why not something like http://www.google.com/forms or http://www.wufoo.com/? You can build a form in Shopify that posts to your server, but you'll need to build the HTML form and the processing end of things on your server.

Comment: can you send some sample , how to do it.

Answer (score 2):

You can create a form that uses POST to send data to your DB. Of course you can. It is simple. Become a Shopify Partner. Create an App, with an App Proxy selected. Now use that Proxy as the endpoint that points to your server and DB. You'll be saving images, forms, whatever you want, securely and with whatever info you need.

You may want to store the customer ID, and the cart token for example, allowing you to connect any uploaded info to the customer and potential order.

Shopify is wicked for this, and very much capable of allowing you to hook up whatever you want.

Comment: Thanks a lot. Am a shopify partner only. Where can i create app an how to use that proxy as the end point. Do you have any examples or any doc for that. please provide me any samples so that i can implement it

Answer (score 0):

Shopify is a hosted platform. If offers you theming and nothing more. You will *not* be able to do any server-side programming such as connecting to a website.

The only option you have is, to create a separate, externally-hosted application in front of your database, that exposes it via an API. Then, use AJAX to submit your form submissions.

The down side is your form will only function is your user is a browser with JavaScript enabled/available. But that’s the cost of using a hosted platform and not having total control.

Comment: so we can't create a form which will be connected and stored in our db in Shopify?

Comment: @user3599302 No. Shopify doesn’t give you access to your database on their platform. That isn’t what you asked in your original question, either. You asked about connecting to an _external_ database.

Comment: yes. i googled and got the same answer what you told that shopify cant give the access to us. that's why we thought of external database. And also heard that zopier app is used to connect external db in shopify. but it is not free. so am here to ask can we do customization and connect our external db to shopify so that we can create the forms and use them. Is there any way?

Comment: @user3599302 Yes. I explained how in my answer.